# How to wait for command line activity to finish before calling another function?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, batch-file, command-line, vbscript

Here is my code. We use a set of commands for our msbuild process. Depending on the environment the command and other activities varies a little bit. So, I came up with something as following. But, there are some commands which takes a while(1m approx) to finish. My script doesn't wait. And, MoveStagedFolders() function doesn't kick off. I executed this function separately and it works. So I my problems are:

1. Why MoveStagedFolders() is not being called?
2. How to wait until commandline activities are done.

   ```
       Option Explicit
       Dim wshShell, environment, strBuildDirectory, strWebsiteDirectory
       On Error Resume Next
       strBuildDirectory = "someFoldersPath\*"
       strWebsiteDirectory = "\\DestinationPath\"
       environment = InputBox("Please Enter the Environment.")

       if  Trim(environment) <> "" then
           Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
           wshShell.Run "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
           WScript.Sleep 500   
           wshShell.sendkeys "cd c:\Program Files +9x86+0\Microsoft Visual Studio 13.0\Common7\Tools"
           wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
           wshShell.sendkeys "vsvars32.bat"
           wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
           wshShell.sendkeys "cd c:\working\develop"
           wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
           wshShell.sendkeys "msbuild/t:clean"
           wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
           wshShell.sendkeys "msbuild/p:configuration=" & environment
           wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}" 
           'I need to wait about a minute here.
           if UCase(environment) = "QA" then
               'Restart IIS
               wshShell.sendkeys "iisreset /restart localhost"
               wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"

           elseif environment = "123" then
               'I need to move some folders to shared folder
               Call MoveStagedFolders()
               'Wait until the moving is done
               if MoveStagedFolders = true then
                   'MsgBox "Restarting IIS"
                   wshShell.sendkeys "iisreset /restart devIp"
                   wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
               end if
           end if
       else
           MsgBox "No environment was entered. Build may not succeed."
       end if

       Function MoveStagedFolders()
           With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
               'Need to overwrite folders
               .CopyFolder strBuildDirectory, strWebsiteDirectory, true
           End With
           MoveStagedFolders = true
       End Function
   ```

Comment: I don't think `SendKeys` is your best option. Can you put all of your commands in a `BAT` file and call that batch file from your VBScript? If you call it using the `Run` function and pass `True` as the 3rd parameter, your VBScript will wait for the batch file to complete before continuing.

Comment: I knew it's not a best option. I op course give it a shot. Thanks for a QUICK answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `SendKeys` for this. Put all your commands in a batch file and call that.

Second, you can make your batch file wait for a command to complete by using the `START` command, like this:

```
START /WAIT MyProgram.exe
```